# two canvases with same GUI Controls

Tags: html, events, canvas, hyperlink, p5.js

How do we link two canvases (one showing 2d drawing and other 3d) on a webpage using JavaScript and P5.js so that if one shape is modified then it also affects the other canvas shapes?

Yeah, thank you. How they can be linked/interactive? If we change drawing in first screen, other screen also show that change.

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like you're looking for **instance mode**.

You can read more about instance mode [here](https://github.com/processing/p5.js/wiki/Global-and-instance-mode), but basically it allows you to have multiple sketches running on the same page.

Get something very simple working, such as showing a circle on one canvas and a rectangle on another canvas. Then build up from there.